# redux-saga: Calling saga from another file

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I have several saga files.
One for navigation one for editing.
So I want in my editing saga 
"SAVE_USER"
after some action insert saga from navigation saga file "GO_TO_ROOT"
wait until it finished and continue the rest of "SAVE_USER"?

editing-saga.js

```
export function* sagaUser(action) {
  try {
    console.log("preparing user")
    console.log("saving user")
     yield put({
      type: "GO_TO_ROOT",
      payload: { true }
    });
    console.log("user saved")
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```

navigation-saga.js

```
export function* goToRoot(action) {
  try {
    console.log("preparing going to root")
    yield call(goToRoot);
    console.log("go to root success")
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to just call `yield` on another saga. For example:

```js
import { goToRoot } from './navigation-saga.js'

export function* sagaUser(action) {
  try {
    console.log("preparing user")
    console.log("saving user")

    yield goToRoot({
      type: "GO_TO_ROOT",
      payload: { true },
    });

    console.log("user saved")
  } catch (e) { }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A clear benefit of using sagas is that you're able to achieve better separation of concerns. But you end up having a lot of more message passing ( actions ) between sagas. One solution of your problem can be the root saga dispatching an action (GO_TO_ROOT_SUCCESS) which can be listened on to by the edit-saga. Something like -

**action**

```js
const gotoSuccess = {
  type: "GO_TO_SUCCESS",
};
```

**navigation-saga.js**

```js
export function* goToRoot(action) {
  try {
     // some logic
     yield put(gotoSuccess);
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```

**editing-saga.js**

```js
export function* sagaUser(action) {
  try {
     yield put({
      type: "GO_TO_ROOT",
      payload: { true }
    });

     yield take("GO_TO_SUCCESS");

    // some more logic
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: so function "sagaUser" will wait until "GO_TO_SUCCESS" action and then continue?